Share Yocto SState cache on server for different build clients. Yokto Kirkstone
I am currently using Yocto 4.0.14 Kirkstone - Bitbake Version 2.0.0
I am still a beginner when it comes to using Yocto.
The SState cache data is on an internal (HTTPS) cache server.
I would like to use this cache from various devices.
The goal is maximum build security and as much time savings as possible.
What I am looking for is a "best practice" on how to do this.
Up until now I thought that it was enough to set SState_Mirror correctly.
But since I then get this warning:
WARNING: You are using a local hash equivalence server but have configured an sstate mirror. This will likely mean no sstate will match from the mirror. You may wish to disable the hash equivalence use (BB_HASHSERVE), or use a hash equivalence server alongside the sstate mirror.
I assumed that I cannot ignore this warning.
And now I have been looking for a while for what exactly I have to set. I have received various error messages and tried a lot.
With my current settings I have no error messages and no warnings.
I currently have
SSTATE_MIRRORS ?= "file://.* https://xxx.c.de/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH"
BB_HASHSERVE = ""
BB_HASHSERVE_UPSTREAM = ""
BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER = ""

set.
And it looks like it's not working properly.
After changing a recipe, it wasn't recognized that part of the cache could no longer be used and had to be recreated. The Bitbake build aborted. It only worked again after deleting the specific files in the SState mirror cache on my server.
Who has an answer to the question of what minimal settings/configurations I need to make this work?

I think that as long as the machines using the mirror find the objects in the sstate cache of the mirror, you can safely ignore the warning.
Here’s how the sstate cache mechanism works, as I understand it:
BitBake generates a hash for each task of each recipe based on several factors: environment variables, the hashes of the tasks on which the current task depends, and more.
If you rebuild the recipe and nothing has changed, it will generate the same hash and find the task already done in the local cache.
If something changes that affects the hash but doesn’t alter the result of the recipe, the local equivalence hash server comes into play. It records in a database the equivalence between the old and new hashes, avoiding the need to rebuild the recipe.
If the hash is not found in the local cache, BitBake will check the mirror cache. In such a case, it’s possible that the local equivalence hash server considers the hash invalid, while if you had configured the mirror equivalence hash server, you could have avoided the rebuild.
If you want to use the equivalence hash server from the mirror in addition to the local one (and avoid the warning), you can do the following:
BB_HASHSERVE_UPSTREAM = "xxx.c.de:6789"
then, on the xxx.c.de machine, launch the hashserver with this command
nohup bitbake-hashserv -b xxx.c.de:6789 -d <path-to-hashserv.db>
This is a useful link where all the concepts are explained better than I have:
https://www.thegoodpenguin.co.uk/blog/improving-yocto-build-time/
